# No "Open in new tab" option in Okular 0.22.0

Tags: tabs, settings, kde-plasma, okular

Since the version 0.19, Okular has a tabbed interface. But in my version (0.22.0) I don't see the "Open in new tab" option in the settings (as explained in the Okular documentation). I precise that my installation is under a Gnome environment. What should I do to make the tab feature working ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to enable checkbox "Open new files in tabs" first in the Okular settings. After that "Open..." command will open new file in tab instead of new Okular instance.

Comment: Thanks, but I have no such option in my okular installation. I checked all entries in the configure - okular dialog.

Comment: Strange. I have this checkbox in "Program Features" section near "Obey DRM limitations" checkbox. But then again I have 0.24.0 version under KDE.

Comment: i'm on centos7... okular version 0.16.5... so no "open new files in tabs" feature in the options.